# Start Hadoop cluster using sbin/start-dfs.sh

Tags: php, hadoop

I want to start Hadoop daemons with PHP instead of terminal.

When i do start-dfs.sh, it works well.

The PHP code I'm using is

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec('/usr/local/hadoop3/sbin/stop-dfs.sh');
?>
```

the output of the above code is

> Starting namenodes on [localhost] starting datanodes. Starting
>   secondary namenodes [chbpc-VirtualBox] .

but when i type the url `http://localhost:9870/dfshealth.html#tab-overview` in the browser (to check the status of my Hadoop), it actually did not start despite having the output above.

Comment: I suggest you install Apache Amarbi rather than start making your own Hadoop dashboard

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec('/usr/local/hadoop3/sbin/stop-dfs.sh > /dev/null &');
?>
```

**Description**

When you run the daemon process with shell_exec, you should detach from this process for finished your shell_exec command, but you should stay daemon process in progress state.

`&` - provide doing this.

Also instead /dev/null you may be using your custom log file and all info from stop-dfs.sh will redirect to this file.

**My test for this solution**

Copy this snippet to your bash console:

```sh
cat <<EOT > daemon.sh
while true; do date; sleep 1; done

EOT

chmod +x daemon.sh

cat <<EOT > daemon-runner.php
<?php
    echo shell_exec(__DIR__ . '/daemon.sh > daemon-log &');

EOT

touch daemon-log

php daemon-runner.php

tail -f daemon-log
```

**PS**

You using `stop-dfs.sh` script name for start your hadoop, also maybe you mixed up script name with `start.sh`?

Comment: i have tried this code. but it does not display any result and also my hadoop is not stopping

Comment: Did you try run `/usr/local/hadoop3/sbin/stop-dfs.sh` manually? This script stop your hadoop if you run this manually in your bash?

Comment: hm, it's very strangers, I suggest to you, try run this php script:
`<?php
    echo shell_exec('/usr/local/hadoop3/sbin/stop-dfs.sh > /tmp/stop-log &');
?>`
and after run, you should will see `/tmp/stop-log` file `cat /tmp/stop-log` for additional details of stoping process.

Comment: Also maybe your php user - `www-data` have not permission for stoping your hadoop. For check this case try to run your script as sudo like this:
`<?php
    echo shell_exec('echo YOUR_SUDO_PASSWORD | sudo -S /usr/local/hadoop3/sbin/stop-dfs.sh > /dev/null &');`
or see this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115054/php-shell-exec-permission-on-linux-ubuntu

Comment: no am getting the same output: Stoping namenodes on [localhost] stoping datanodes. Stoping secondary namenodes [chbpc-VirtualBox] .but when i check the url: http://localhost:9870/dfshealth.html#tab-overview in the browser (to check the status of my Hadoop), it actually did not stop